# How do I duplicate items?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I just retrieved the Jagged Crown in Skyrim for Xbox 360, and see that it sells for 5000 gold. I heard that there is a duplication glitch in putting the item on a mannequin.

Anyone know how to do this?  Where can I find one in the game?  I do not yet have a house.

Comment: To downvoter: why?

Comment: I was also wondering actually. Perhaps your question isn't general enough. Try this, rewrite the question to be about your main point. You want to know if it is possible to duplicate items. (A rather basic cheat, I would say). If you do that, I think you would get upvotes. Even better, make it as general as possible, so include not only the xbox360, but all systems. (You are only interested in the xbox version, but others do not share this).

Comment: @Ids Glitches are often system specific, so I think the question works just fine being XBox specific.

Comment: Just to add to this, if you are interested in a "glitch free" version of making fast cash enchanted banish items are extremely valuable. If you make about 100 iron daggers and enchant them with banish each will sell for around 1200 gold.

Comment: This question is pointless if you're playing on PC. If you want to cheat, just give yourself the gold with the console.

Comment: Actually, that tag shouldn't have been removed. Putting that back in.

Answer (score 4):

> #### Requirements
>
> - Must have completed Dark Brotherhood questline
> - Must have got the Mannequin upgrade in the new Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary.
>
> #### The Guide
>
> Firstly, make sure you have the requirements stated above. Now, go to
> the sanctuary in dawnstar. Proceed to the room with the Mannequin.
> Click on the Mannequin to activate it. Press Square (PS3) or X (Xbox)
> to store your desired apparel into the Mannequin. Now, do NOT back out
> of the menu. Go back up to 'Apparel' on the mannequin and take your
> armour back out. Now, exit the menu and equip the armour that you had
> originally put in the Mannequin.
>
> Next, quickly leave the Sanctuary. Once you have left, re-enter and go
> back to the Mannequin. You will notice that if you have done it right,
> the Mannequin will have your apparel equipped. Take it off him, and
> repeat if you want to keep getting sets of armour.

<sup>Source: http://skyrimforums.org/threads/slight-spoiler-guide-how-to-duplicate-apparel.825/</sup>
Also, for PC, the console command `player.additem DA750 (number you want goes here)` will do exactly that; add the number you want of the crown in your inventory. Or you could do `000000f` or just `f`, which is gold.

Comment: Could you post actual instructions here, instead of just a link to an outside reference?

Comment: I am looking for the xbox360 actually.

Comment: @Bobby This answer has Xbox 360 instructions. Try it and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Another trick I've noticed that I would like to share is the inconsistency within the houses offered in the Hearthfire DLC. I'm unsure of how to properly do this, but I've cloned almost every set of armor I've had using the mannequin in the Lakeview Manor. As you know, the duplication glitch has been patched, but for some strange reason it can be achieved within these three following houses: Lakeview Manor, Windstad Manor, and Heljarchen Hall. As soon as you purchase one of these houses, it's imperative that you immediately put on any armor and/or clothing on one of the mannequins in any one of those selected houses (preferably in the armory). When exiting your house and arriving back, usually after quite some time you'll notice loading inconsistencies within the house. This can be seen by invisible mannequins and/or mannequins improperly placed in front of the pedestal. When this happens you want you want to remove whatever items you've placed on them quickly and exit the house. On arrival, those items will have reappeared. Once you have the Black Market power it's extremely useful for unloading valued cloned items such as the Jagged Crown.

Answer (score 0):

Yes on the xbox 360 and probably ps3 as well, put item on mannequin, remove, exit building, re-enter building, and it should have duplicated it. I did this with the ebony mail (Awesome daedric artifact) and thedark brotherhood armor. there is one later in the dark brotherhood quest, once you go to the secoond sanctuary.

Also you said you didn't have a house, well here's how to get a free one; Get the right to buy one by 1.helping the jarl. 2.save 3. talk to the steward and go through as if you were going to buy it, but once you say you want one he'll start talking, exit conversation, and sprint to a chest/cupboard etc. put all your money in it before you hear the coin giving noise, then retrieve your money after he finishes talking, also works with house expansions or additions, whichever you call them

Comment: Note:  It seems your "house for free" solution still requires that you have enough money to buy the house on-hand.  Sure, you end up not having to actually pay for it in the end but you still have to earn the cash up front.

Answer (score 0):

Required Dawnstar Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary and must have purchased the master bedroom set to get the mannequin [Purchased from Delvin Malory] follow the Thievs Build Questline to find him.Now your ready to begin duplicating first put whatever armour you want duplicated on the mannequin but don't exit!Then go to the mannequin apparel and remove what you put on it then exit the sanctuary,fast travel to Whiterun [that's what worked for me]then fast travel back to the sanctuary and the mannequin should have duplicated your armour!Hope this helped, btw this is for Xbox 360 and possibly Ps3 Happy Duplicating! :-)